# How to send email from manualValidation@0

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

```yaml
- stage: approval
    jobs:
    - job: memberlist
      pool: 
        name: Azure Pipelines
        vmImage: 'windows-2019'   
      steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              try {
                $redmineUrl = "http://redmine/projects/${env:REDMINEPROJECTID}/memberships.json?key={key}&limit=100&Content-Type=application/json"
                Write-Host $redmineUrl
                $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $redmineUrl -Method Get
                $redmineData = $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json 
                # Write-Host $redmineData
                $filteredUsers = $redmineData.memberships | Where-Object {
                  # dev members
                    $_.roles.id -contains 4 -or
                    $_.roles.id -contains 9 -or
                    $_.roles.id -contains 14 -or
                    $_.roles.id -contains 17 #-or
                    # PM members
                    # $_.roles.id -contains 3 -or
                    # architect members
                    # $_.roles.id -contains 16 -or
                    # $_.roles.id -contains 25 
                }
                $userIDs = $filteredUsers.user.id
                $emailAddresses = @()
                Write-Host $userIDs
                foreach ($userID in $userIDs) {
                  $userUrl = "http://redmine/users/${userID}.json?key=946b8ee19b89bbe02b3ffd140eed83acd90b9724"
                  $userDetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userUrl -Method Get
                  $userData = $userDetails | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | ConvertFrom-Json
                  $userEmail = $userData.user.mail
                  $emailAddresses += $userEmail
                }
                Write-Host $emailAddresses
                $emailAddressesString = $emailAddresses -join ";"
                Write-Host $emailAddressesString
                Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DevMembers;isOutput=true]$emailAddresses"
                # Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymentCounter;isOutput=true]1"
                
              }catch {
                  Write-Host "Error: $_"
              }
          name: ProjectmembersDev
    - job: waitForValidation
      dependsOn: memberlist
      displayName: Wait for Approval  
      pool: server    
      timeoutInMinutes: 4320
      variables:
        DevStageVar: $[dependencies.memberlist.outputs['ProjectmembersDev.DevMembers']]
      steps: 
        - task: ManualValidation@0
          timeoutInMinutes: 1440 
          inputs:
            notifyUsers: |
              $(DevStageVar)
              name1@email.com
              name2@email.com
              name3@email.com   
            instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
            onTimeout: 'reject'
          condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['DevStageVar'], ''))
          name: validation
```

above is my code for extracting mail IDs for respective projects and adding manual validation to notify users and try to send them mail.
I'm able to receive the mail but others who are not in the organization in azure project setting are not able to receive the mail.
suggest to me how can i tackle this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the **`notifyUsers`** set on the **`ManualValidation@0`** task should have been invited into the Azure DevOps organization and also have the access to the project and the pipelines. Because the notified users need to sign in to the Azure DevOps organization to manually complete the approval/reject the waiting pipeline run.

If the user is not invited into the organization, it will be an invalid user that cannot access the organization, so it will not be notified.

So, if you want to set a user as one of the **`notifyUsers`** on the **`ManualValidation@0`** task, you should invite that user into your Azure DevOps organization and give it the required permissions to access the project and pipelines.